# How to save ZfcUser display name

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm trying to save the display name of a user account using ZfcUser as a base to create my own API, but unfortunately I couldn't. This is my code:

```
$service = $this->getUserService();
$form = $this->getPostData();
$post = array(
        "email" => $form->{'email'},
        "password" => $form->{'password'},
        "passwordVerify" => $form->{'password'},
        "display_name" => $form->{'name'},
        "submit" => ""
        );

$service->register($post);
return new JsonModel($this->postToArray($form));
```

Comment: Do you have option "enable_display_name" set on true? Default value is false and in that case is display name skipped from validation, hydration and so on in UserService.

Comment: Yeah, I actually try to set this line: $service->getOptions()->setEnableDisplayName(true); before $service->register($post), but it didn't work... It isn't saving the display_name in the DB. Thanks anyway

Comment: Even if I print the $user array I get this:
object(ZfcUserDoctrineMongoODM\Document\User)#295 (6) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(24) "5395e69e1c785a3e721446ab"
  ["username":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["email":protected]=>
  string(22) "javierdlahoz@gmail.com"
  ["displayName":protected]=>
  string(12) "javierdlahoz"
  ["password":protected]=>
  string(60) "$2y$14$Qbs5Lp/E7KKfAlfMoliyQuORofEMtIXSr0Wa8XHALHJi.i68le5Oq"
  ["state":protected]=>
  NULL
}
But display_name is null on the user document

Comment: Well, it may not be enough (set it via setter somewhere) for example, register form could be already cached in user service with removed field for display_name. Try to set it in configuration file.

Comment: I'm gonna try, but actually, if I set this line $service->getOptions()->setEnableUsername(true); I can add username field to the user document, so it should work in the same way for display_name

Comment: Now I noticed difference between display_name in your code and displayName in data (camelCase vs underscore_case). What is in your XML mapping?

Comment: I solved this little problem extending the User Entity and using annotations instead of XML, so thanks for your replies